# category filed dont appear in api create form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm playing with `django rest` framework and my problem was category and tags `fileds` don't appear in api create form or update form, I'm using `ModelSerializer`, how can I fix this?

serializers.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from markdown import markdown
from users.models import *
from rest_framework import serializers
from articles.models import *


class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ouser
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar')


class TagModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        exclude = ['updated_at', 'created_at']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'tag-api', 'lookup_field': 'slug'},
        }


class CategoryModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        exclude = ['updated_at', 'created_at']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'category-api', 'lookup_field': 'slug'},
        }


class ArticleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserModelSerializer(read_only=True)
    content_as_markdown = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='article-api',
        lookup_field='slug'
    )
    category = CategoryModelSerializer(read_only=True)
    tags = TagModelSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['updated_at', 'created_at']

    def get_date(self, obj):
        return obj.published_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")

    def get_content_as_markdown(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(markdown(obj.content, safe_mode='escape'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've set `read_only=True` on them. This literally causes what you've got - fields are not present on any create or update calls.

Comment: but when i remove read_only it appear like input text i want appear like select option

Comment: That's a totally different question... For that to work, you have to provide separate serializer for creating or updating.